# Angular Fixtures for Development with Grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm looking for a way to fixture data when in development of the front end, but when I build the minified version of the javascript, it will tie in the REST calls rather than the fixtured data.

I'm using a service to abstract away the implementation of calling the backend, so should I have two service Javascript implementations, one for development, another for the build, or is there an easier way to call a URL and have something intercept the URL and return fixtured data.

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a javascript file that will be excluded from the build, but included when doing a grunt serve locally as follows:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('mockHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
    return {
      'request' : function (config) {
        if (config.url === '/testUrl') {
          // Rewrite the URL to avoid a 404 locally.
          config.url = '#/mock/testUrl';
        }
        return config;
      },

      'response' : function (response) {
        // Check to see if it's the mock url you want to fixture.
        if (response.config.url === '#/mock/testUrl') {
          // Set the data you want in the response.
          response.data = { name: 'John Smith' };
        }
        return response;
      }
    }
  });

angular.module('myApp')
  .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('mockHttpInterceptor');
  }]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just an update, if you want to test in IE, don't use # to signify the new URL, IE doesn't seem to like that.  I used ? as a workaround.